Using React Native in a DreamService on Android
I am trying to create a React Native view inside a DreamService on Android, but I can not find a way to work.
It seems that since the DreamService is a service, not an activity, a lot of the functionality is missing.
Below is the closest i got, but it fails with java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.facebook.react.ReactDelegate.loadApp()' on a null object reference.
Anyone know is there is a way to get a full view up and running?
    override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow()
        isInteractive = true
        val reactNativeFragment = ReactFragment.Builder()
            .setComponentName("HelloWorld")
        .setLaunchOptions(Bundle().apply { putString("message", "my value") })
        .build()
        val bundle = Bundle()
        val fragment = reactNativeFragment.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.from(this), null, bundle);
        setContentView(fragment);
    }

Note: the app is newly created using npx @react-native-community/cli@latest init
